# In VIM, why does the cursor move with 4yk but not 4yj?

Tags: vim, neovim

To yank 4 lines up from the current position + the current line, I can use `4yk`, and to yank 4 lines down from the current position + the current line, i can use `4yj`

But `4yk` moves the cursor, whereas `4yj` does not (at least in the version of vim i am using, neovim).

Why is this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cursor moves to the first line of the motion.

With `4yk` (or any similar upward motion), the first line of the motion is different from the current line so the cursor moves.

With `4yj` (or any similar downward motion), the first line of the motion is the current line so the cursor doesn't move.

From `:help operator`:

```
After applying the operator the cursor is mostly left at the start of the text
that was operated upon.  For example, "yfe" doesn't move the cursor, but "yFe"
moves the cursor leftwards to the "e" where the yank started.
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to yank downwards, the best solution to what you're asking would be `4yy`. That way, it yanks 4 lines, plus it accounts for any CRs, and so if you Put between two lines, it makes space for whatever you're putting. For example:

`1  Shall I compare thee to a summer's day? 
2  Thou art more lovely and more temperate:
3  Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,
4  And summer's lease hath all too short a date: 
5  Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,
6  And often is his gold complexion dimm'd; 
7  And every fair from fair sometime declines,
8  By chance, or nature's changing course, untrimm'd;
9  But thy eternal summer shall not fade
10 Nor lose possession of that fair thou ow'st;
11 Nor shall Death brag thou wander'st in his shade,
12 When in eternal lines to time thou grow'st; 
13 So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,
14 So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.`

Let's say you have your cursor at Line #5, and you do `4yy`, it'll yank 4 lines down. Then, if you go (for example) to Line #12 and press `p` (or to Line #13 and press `P`, capital), you'll get:

`1  Shall I compare thee to a summer's day? 
2  Thou art more lovely and more temperate:
3  Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,
4  And summer's lease hath all too short a date: 
5  Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,
6  And often is his gold complexion dimm'd; 
7  And every fair from fair sometime declines,
8  By chance, or nature's changing course, untrimm'd;
9  But thy eternal summer shall not fade
10 Nor lose possession of that fair thou ow'st;
11 Nor shall Death brag thou wander'st in his shade,
12 When in eternal lines to time thou grow'st; 
13 **Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,**
14 **And often is his gold complexion dimm'd;** 
15 **And every fair from fair sometime declines,**
16 **By chance, or nature's changing course, untrimm'd;**
17 So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,
18 So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.`

(the asterisks are obviously mine).

`4yj` doesn't actually do anything because, exactly as romainl said, the first line of motion is the current line, so the cursor doesn't move. This is why you have to use `4yy` and not `4yj`.